# Evaluating files with embedded code using Groovy Shell

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I'm a web developer that recently moved from using PHP to Java for web applications. I ended up writing my own server application that was easily extendable using uncompiled groovy scripts that my server would evaluate through a Groovy Shell -- ie. `foo.html.groovy`. To this day it works wonders and I'm very proud of my results... BUT... there is one thing I very much miss from PHP scripts, that I would like to implement inside my application and that's the ability to embed the programming language code inside the file. Not only do I miss it for convince, I also miss it because using many `print` statements to output html, or similar, is quickly becoming a pain, not to mention that Groovy does not play well with JavaScript code unless almost everything is escaped -- ie. `$ " '`.

PHP:

```
    <p class="warning"><?php echo($result["error"]); ?></p>
```

Even Ruby on Rails offers something like this with `.erb` files, plus I'd imagine something from Groovy would look like this:

```
    <p class="warning"><%= result.error %></p>
```

I'm just curious if anyone knows if this has been implemented or if it could be emulated? When I was first developing my application I did make attempts at using a Regex formula to filter out the embed code, evaluate it, and replace it back in but this was not 100% flawless and it made debugging any code errors a nightmare since line and column numbers were never accurate. I did also try using Quercus -- which emulates PHP inside Java -- but their project is so outdated, I had I hard time finding documentation or help. So any ideas or direction to solutions would be much appreciated.

If anyone is interested in seeing what I did as reference, [here is my code repository at GitHub](https://github.com/ChioriGreene/ChioriWebServer) -- FYI, my application is a bit overdue for somewhat of an overhaul to the code and structure.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: That embedded code ("scriptlets" in JSP terms) is a nightmare in terms of maintainability, because you get logic scattered everywhere and duplicated. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Grails* (https://grails.org) framework allows for that sort of *templating* (among many other things). It's essentially the *Groovy* equivalent of *Ruby on Rails* (hence the name similarity -- it used to be known as *Groovy on Grails*).

Here's one of their introductory sample apps:

https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-petclinic

It lets you do things like this, within a `<table>` tag:

```
<g:each var="v" in="${visit.pet.visits}">
    <g:if test="${v.id}">
        <tr>
            <td><g:formatDate date="${v.date}" format="yyyy-MM-dd"/></td>
            <td>${v.description}</td>
        </tr>
    </g:if>
</g:each>
```

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

If *Grails* is too heavy-weight and different from what you currently have, you may want to give *Groovy Templates* a try.

These are built in to the language, much lighter weight than *Grails*, and much more similar to the *PHP* style you mentioned and the *JSP Scriplets* that were mentioned in another comment.

This is the example in the [Groovy doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates):

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def text = 'Dear "$firstname $lastname",\nSo nice to meet you in <% print city %>.\nSee you in ${month},\n${signed}'

def binding = ["firstname":"Sam", "lastname":"Pullara", "city":"San Francisco", "month":"December", "signed":"Groovy-Dev"]

def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)

def result = 'Dear "Sam Pullara",\nSo nice to meet you in San Francisco.\nSee you in December,\nGroovy-Dev'

assert result == template.toString()
```

Comment: I've done a little more research into your what you're suggesting with Groovy Server Pages from Grails and sadly, it looks nice and all but it's a Grails specific thing and is not compatible with my application. I've already given Grails a try recently and I don't like how it works and whats involved to develop with it. I ended up using Ruby on Rails instead when I need this sort of thing but this question is about implementing this ability into my application not what provides it or what are the alternatives. Thanks for the answer but I don't think it's going to work for what I need.

Comment: WOW!!! After a quick once over, that looks to be exactly what I NEED. I wish this was better documented else where. Thanks for the help. Now all I need to do is try and implement it.